# Error de Referencia Javascript

Tags: javascript

*Creo que uno de mis grandes problemas en javascript **es la manera en que escribo lo que realizo** y necesito un empujón si alguien puede por qué esto me sucede:*

Estoy obteniendo el siguiente error:

> Reference error: simplefor is not defined

Lo único que se me ocurre es hacer `window.simplefor = function()` , pero no quiero hacerlo por hacer, **a mi me gusta entender porque hago esto y entender realmente el funcionamiento** , cabe destacar que investigo mucho, veo videos, libros y más.

```js
// Simple for loop 1 - 10

function simplefor() {
  var i = 0;
  for (i; i < 10; i++) {

    document.write(i + '\n')

  }
}
```

```html
<h1 style="text-align: center">Learning Javascript</h1>
<hr></hr>
<h5 style="text-align: center">Simple for 1 - 10 </h5>

<script>
  simplefor()
</script>

<hr/>
```

Comment: No estas incluyendo el javascript dentro del html, por eso salta el error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que el editor de código, al montar la página, incluye el código javascript después del código HTML:

[image: Código generado por tu ejemplo]

Por lo tanto la llamada a la función queda antes que la declaración de ésta.

El error te da porque estás intentando llamar a una función que todavía no se ha declarado.

Deberías procurar no incluir código javascript directamente dentro de tu código html (como la llamada a la función simplefor).

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo de cómo podrías sacar el código.
Lo que he hecho es modificar la función simplefor para que reciba como argumento el elemento HTML en el que debe insertar el texto.
En el código HTML he añadido un div en el lugar donde quiero que se añada el texto y se lo paso en la llamada a simplefor:

```js
// Simple for loop 1 - 10

function simplefor(containerElement) {
  var i = 0;
  var text = '';
  for (i; i < 10; i++) {
    text+= i + '\n';
  }
  containerElement.innerText = text;
}

var container = document.getElementById('content');
simplefor(container);
```

```html
<h1 style="text-align: center">Learning Javascript</h1>
<hr></hr>
<h5 style="text-align: center">Simple for 1 - 10 </h5>

<div id="content"></div>

<hr/>
```

Comment: y que hago? porqué yo no quiero incluir el código en el html

Comment: Precisamente el problema es que estás incluyendo código javascript en el html (en concreto la llamada a la función simplefor). He modificado la respuesta para incluir un ejemplo de cómo podrías hacerlo.

Comment: gracias Asier , me ha servido muchísimo :)

Answer (score 1):

Falta incluir la funcion en el codigo html

```html
<script>
  function simplefor() {
    var i = 0;
    for (i; i < 10; i++) {

      document.write(i + '\n')

    }
  }
</script>

<h1 style="text-align: center">Learning Javascript</h1>
<hr></hr>
<h5 style="text-align: center">Simple for 1 - 10 </h5>

<script>
  simplefor();
</script>

<hr />
```

Comment: Faltaría poner el ; después de llamar la función.

Comment: Cierto, copie su codigo y se me paso ponerselo. Editado.